# Load some data asynchronously in Algolia React Instantsearch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm using `algolia` InstantSearch with React to load athletes data like this

```
<InstantSearch
  searchClient={searchClient}
  indexName={`${algoliaEnvironment}_athlete`}
>
  <div className="search-panel">
    <div className="search-panel__results">
      <SearchBox className="searchbox" />
      <InfiniteAthletes />
    </div>
  </div>
</InstantSearch>;
```

in InfiniteAthletes I'm extending InfiniteHits widget to implement infinite scroll functionality.

```
render() {
  const {hits} = this.props;
  ...
  return <TableWrapper
           columns={columns}
           dataSource={hits}
           loading={loading}
           rowKey={record => {
             return record.objectID;
           }}
          />;
   ...
}
...
export default connectInfiniteHits(InfiniteAthletes);
```

In props.hits I get some data about athletes. What I need to do is to asynchronously load athlete avatar(profile picture) into the "hits" props. So on every update in hits I get list of athlete ids, I should send async request to retrieve avatars and then set them into hits props to re-render the result with avatars included. This was easy task when I wasn't using algolia (with setState) but now I can't find a way to implement this and set new data into props.hits manually. I looked into documentation but can't find any info about how to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What kind of call do you have to perform? It one for each hit? Or only one for all hits to get a list of avatars? Is it mandatory that the avatar are stored on each hit? You could imagine a map avatarID:avatar that is used by the TableWrapper to render the list of hits.

Comment: Without using algolia my flow was like this:
1. get avatars list with a call and setstate (which displays list in table), loading image is displayed for avatar by default
2. make separate request to the endpoint which takes list of ids and returns avatar urls for these ids, after this request is finished update athletes list with avatar urls